# How to ask Audio Autoplay permission in the browser(safari) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, safari, autoplay

I am getting this error in Safari(MAC),

[image]

i am implementing a feature that triggers audio alert when a buyer sends a request to the seller. I am able to play muted audio but it show error when it is being played Unmuted.
I want to ask is there any way we can ask users to allow audio play permissin as like we ask geolocation or camera/mic access permission with JavaScript. 
Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
window.MutedAudioPlayed = false;
        window.MyAudio = new Audio("https://XXXX.com/input_sound.mp3");
        window.MyAudio.preload = 'auto';
        window.MyAudio.muted = true;
        window.MyAudio.play().then(function (event) {
            window.MutedAudioPlayed = true;
            console.log('Audio MutedAudioPlayed: ', window.MutedAudioPlayed);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            window.MutedAudioPlayed = false;
            console.log('Audio Play Error: ', error.message);
        });

        window.MyAudio.muted = false; 
        window.MyAudio.play().then(function (event) {
            console.log("Audio Play: ", event);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Audio Play Error: ', error.message);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what we figured so far, you can do the following:

1. Request user the permission for `audio` (that usually stands for microphone, but also works for sounds)
2. Load your sound file and use `AudioBuffer` to play it, see below for example.

```js
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(() => {
        const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.addEventListener('ended', () => {
            source.stop();
            audioContext.close();
        });

        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET', '/path-to-sound.mp3', true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        request.onload = () => {
            audioContext.decodeAudioData(
                request.response,
                (buffer) => {
                    source.buffer = buffer;
                    source.connect(audioContext.destination);
                    source.start();
                },
                (e) => {
                    console.log('Error with decoding audio data' + e.message);
                });
        }

        request.send();
    })
    .catch(reason => console.error(`Audio permissions denied: ${reason}`));
```

This approach has several drawbacks, though:

1. You can't play sound in the background
2. If you do that, the sounds would be queued in Safari and played when tab/window is active again